# Add 'iteration number' column to SQL Select based on same values from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct-values

I have a SQL (SQL Server) statement `SELECT id, animalId, ownerId FROM myTable ORDER BY id` which outputs the following data:

```
id  | animalId | ownerId
------------------------
1   | 123      | 62
2   | 123      | 182
3   | 240      | 27
4   | 2        | 30
5   | 73       | 35
6   | 123      | 62
7   | 108      | 162
8   | 2        | 30
9   | 2        | 30
10  | 73       | 35
```

What I want to be able to do is add a fourth column dynamically that acts as a counter for each row that has the same values for animalId and ownerId.  So the resultant output would be:

```
id  | animalId | ownerId | iterator
-----------------------------------
1   | 123      | 62      | 1           <-- First instance where animalId is 123 and ownerId is 62
2   | 123      | 182     | 1
3   | 240      | 27      | 1
4   | 2        | 30      | 1
5   | 73       | 35      | 1
6   | 123      | 62      | 2           <-- Second instance where animalId is 123 and ownerId is 62
7   | 108      | 162     | 1
8   | 2        | 30      | 2
9   | 2        | 30      | 3
10  | 73       | 35      | 2
```

Could anyone advise how to go about this please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with window function ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT id, animalId, ownerId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY animalId, ownerId ORDER BY id) iterator 
FROM myTable 
ORDER BY id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=003ee08d3484e05afd16452123e23900).
Results:

```
> id | animalId | ownerId | iterator
> -: | -------: | ------: | -------:
>  1 |      123 |      62 |        1
>  2 |      123 |     182 |        1
>  3 |      240 |      27 |        1
>  4 |        2 |      30 |        1
>  5 |       73 |      35 |        1
>  6 |      123 |      62 |        2
>  7 |      108 |     162 |        1
>  8 |        2 |      30 |        2
>  9 |        2 |      30 |        3
> 10 |       73 |      35 |        2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to count occurrences of the pair 123/62 up to a given point (as the comments in the code suggest), then you can use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when ownerid = 62 and animalid = 123 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as iterator
from t;
```

More reasonably, you want this for all pairs.  So, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by ownerid, animalid order by id) as iterator
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you would want results in the order of ID.
Please find below solution which is based on pure ANSI SQL syntax.

**Create table**

```
create table animalOwners( id int, animalId int , ownerId int );
```

**Insert Data **

```
insert into animalOwners values (1,123,62);
insert into animalOwners values(2,123,182);
insert into animalOwners values(3,240,27);
insert into animalOwners values(4,2,30);
insert into animalOwners values(5,73,35);
insert into animalOwners values(6,123,62);
insert into animalOwners values(7,108,162);
insert into animalOwners values(8,2,30);
insert into animalOwners values(9,2,30);
insert into animalOwners values(10,73,35);
```

**SQL Solution :**

```
select
    id,
    animalID,
    ownerId,
    (
    select
        count(*)
    from
        animalOwners innerTable
        where innerTable.id <= outerTable.id
        and innerTable.animalId = outerTable.animalId
        and innerTable.ownerId = outerTable.ownerId ) as counter
from
    animalOwners outerTable
order by
    id;
```

If you run this you would get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is “windowing functions”.  You can sequence the members in the group (row_number over (partition by columns order by columns), count the members of the group (count(1) over (partition by column)), rank them, sum them, average them, etc.